# How to create my own "shell" command line program in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, swift, shell, command-line, osx-yosemite

I wondering about how can I create my own command line or shell program like "cat", "git" etc... with Swift and Xcode?

For example:

```
rod -a "hello world!" 
rod --version
rod /list -e "bye world!"
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably the following:

1. open a terminal window and navigate to the directory of your choice
2. Create an empty swift file by entering the terminal command

   ```
   touch myFirstProgram.swift
   ```
3. Make this file executable by entering the terminal command

   ```
   chmod +x myFirstProgram.swift
   ```
4. Open this directory in finder by entering the terminal command

   ```
   open .
   ```
5. Double-click on myFirstProgram.swift to open the empty file in Xcode. Then, inside Xcode, write the following lines into your first swift program. The first line starts the swift interpreter, anything after that is simple swift code.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

   println("Hello world.")
   ```
6. After saving your program, you can start this by entering the terminal command

   ```
   ./myFirstProgram.swift
   ```

done.

Once you have understood these steps, you can go out and explore freely. I found, for example, an excellent first tutorial at
http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/07/swift-scripts-how-to-write-small-command-line-scripts-in-swift/. The only outdated information I found there was that the first line of the swift program should be as I detailed in point 5 (without a "-i" at the end of the line).

Have fun!

Comment: Thx, is possible to add an Alias for ./myFirstProgram.swift to start the program by typing "awe" for example?

Comment: on my computer it isn't: I'm afraid I am not familiar with the program "awe". Since you mentioned "cat", and "git" in your question, you might mean "awk", which means I should probably explain something: these commands are programs just like "myFirstProgram.swift". "cat" shows the contents of a file, "git" is a version control program, "awk" is something like a programming language. If you enter these keywords first, everything else will be an argument of this command (e.g. "git clone ..." means "git" is the command", "clone ..." are arguments). Cheers

Comment: PS: If you are interested in these things, may I suggest you work through a couple of python tutorials. I trust that the above-mentioned concepts will become clearer. Enjoy!

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, im trying to say that I want to create my own shell command like, git, cat, ls, mkdir, etc. so when I want to use my program using the terminal i can use my custom name, for example: $rod -h "doworknow"

Comment: yes, this is how ;-)

If you add your working directory to your *path*, you can just write *myFirstProgram.swift*. And if you really want, you can even rename *myFirstProgram.swift* to *rod*, and then you can write *rod -whatever youDecide*. Please do refer to the link I sent to you. Cheers!